# Link-only answers linking to Stack Overflow content

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, link-only-answers

I guess it would be easy to detect automatically and provide a path inside the review queue. I'm asking because of this exchange earlier today:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. –  OtherDude 1 hour ago
>
> @OtherDude when the page he is linking is another post on Stack Overflow, it is not the case to flag it as a dupe? –  Paulo Scardine 1 hour ago
>
> @PauloScardine: please feel free to flag as a dupe if you believe it should be. This post was presented to me via the review queue and judging whether the linked article is in fact a valid duplicate is outside the scope of that activity. – OtherDude 27 mins ago

OK, I flagged it as a dupe, but I was wondering why "judging whether the linked article is in fact a valid duplicate is outside the scope of that activity".

Since link-only answers pointing to another post on Stack Overflow are easy to detect, we could add a queue for that or provide a path inside the queue to flag question as a dupe and delete answer.

What do you think?

Answer (score 16):

Every answer that consists of only a link, regardless of the link content's source, should be flagged as *link-only* answer. What will happen if the linked answer was changed or deleted? Or even the original question was deleted?

If you think the post is duplicate, you should vote to close the question, and not flag the answer as duplicate.

Comment: I've voted to close it (because it was indeed a dupe), my point is that linking to another post is a strong smell for duplicates and it would be nice to vote to close as a dupe from inside the queue.

Comment: @PauloScardine You can filter the *close vote* queue and select only duplicated questions, it'll probably be there. If not, I think the best thing to do is voting to close manually, IMHO it's redundant to have such a queue only in these situations.

Comment: Yes, having another queue would be redundant. How about having a shortcut to delete the answer and vote to close the question as well?

Comment: I just had similar conversation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114627/5779732. I incorrectly reviewed the post; corrected my mistake when I read this.